# Assign C++ class member function to C struct function pointer

Tags: c++, stream, virtual, avr

I facing with a problem and giving up thinking for days on it, I turn to you for a possible solution or idea.

I writing some classes for an AVR micro to have standard functions for writing and receiving data and use them to create a stream to use with STDIN and STDOUT.
The definition of the file structure in stdio.h is:

```
  struct __file {
      char *buf; /* buffer pointer */
      unsigned char unget; /* ungetc() buffer */
      uint8_t flags; /* flags, see below */
      int size; /* size of buffer */

      int len; /* characters read or written so far */
      int (*put)(char, struct __file *); /* function to write one char to device */
      int (*get)(struct __file *); /* function to read one char from device */
      void *udata; /* User defined and accessible data. */
    };
```

I want to create a base class with pure virtual functions `send` and `receive`
(for UART, networking, I2c) and assign them to the file structure's `put` and `get` functions.

I know about the C and C++ signature incompatibility, so I need a workaround.
Since the file structure's `get` and `put` arguments are already declared and due to the virtual functions, I can't use callback method. Actually I can declare a static pointer, and make a callback to `send` and `receive` member functions from the C function, but it would work only with one instance.

```
class Stream{
private:
    FILE Stream;
    static Stream* instance;

    Stream(){
        _stream.put=putChar;
        _stream.get=getChar;
        _stream.flags=_FDEV_SETUP_RW;
    }

    virtual int send(char c)=0;
    virtual int receive()=0;

    static int putchar(char c, FILE* stream){
        return (instance->send(c));
    }

    static int getchar(FILE* stream){
       return (instance->receive);
    }
}
```

Silly idea:
I have small knowledge on templates, but could it be done with template classes? I was thinking to create the static pointer with some template solution, but no idea how could be done.

Or is it simpler to say that my design idea is a dead end?

**Jarod42 gave me the solution:
You may use `void *udata;` to store your instance pointer (and cast back in the `getchar`/`putchar` call). **

Comment: You may use `void *udata;` to store your instance pointer (and cast back in the `getchar`/`putchar` call).

Comment: _"but could it be done with template classes?"_ What should be the value of using a template? Which types do you plan being a template parameter?

Comment: I can't believe it it was in front of me all along. LOL.
I wasn't sure about the use of that pointer, but as you point on it, 
completely make sense. I'll try to deal with it.

Comment: As I mentioned, I know only a small about templates, so I don't know all the possibilities. I was googling for template classes with static pointers, etc to see that I can go along with that, but dead end.

Comment: I just assigned the udata with the this object pointer than in the static function I did  static_cast<Stream*>(stream->udata)->send(c) and it compiles nicely. I really appreciate your help.
Big thank you!